# Is there any way add data in a dataframe without any changes to Data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Data looks like this

H1234|1234|1999-12-03.3.22.34.132456
G1345|2345|1998-11-03-12.22.45.23456

I stored this data on a List[String], while converting it to a data frame by doing:

```scala
val dataframe = list.map(r => r.split("\\|")).map(r => (r(0),r(1),r(2)).toDF("ID","Number","Timestamp ")
```

but when I am using dataframe.show, the Timestamp Column, I am getting it as below:

(FYI every value is a String)

| Timestamp |
| --- |
| 1999-12-03.3.22.... |
| 1998-11-03-12.22... |

Could you please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867147/convert-list-into-dataframe-spark-scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is actually intact, but `show` is truncating the output. Do `dataframe.show(false)` to avoid truncation of output.

Comment: @mike I saw your link, but given that the OP got a timestamp column with two rows, I suspect the OP managed to build a proper dataframe... anyway let's wait for the OP's response

Comment: I just wrote a little bit of code where i am applying transformation.... If you want I can write the whole code. I just wanted to give you guys a basic idea of what my data looks like and what problem I faced @mck